# Getting buffering progress value in HTML5 video player

Tags: html, html5-video, buffering

In Firefox, when I see the simple video element in [this example](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html), it has default browser controls. Right after the page is loaded the video starts to load; I see how the buffering (loading) line is moving to the right side of the default browser controls.

**How can I get this value for the buffer?**

I have tried a number of different ways, including `video.buffered` and `progress event listener` with `e.total`, `e.loaded`.

I have Firefox 3.6.3, which doesn't seem to support `.buffered` or `.total / .loaded`.

How do the default browser controls initialize this buffering progress?

By the way, I have other examples of different HTML5 players, which do the same as the default browser controls:

- http://sublimevideo.net/demo
- http://videojs.com

Answer (score 8):

View the source at this example :

http://people.mozilla.com/~cpearce/buffered-demo.html

Essentially, you need to get your control and check the "buffered" property of it.

```
var v = document.getElementById('buffered_v');
var r = v.buffered.end(0);
```

That should be your buffered value.

Comment: Cool and very useful!